# postgresql notification channel

Tags: java, postgresql

I am currently playing with the Notify/Listen mechanism of postgresql and try to combine it with the trigger to detect changes in db tables and send it to a external watcher written in Java. During my test I found that it seems the channel created by either notify or listen will not last if there is no connection to it. For example, if a notifier execute a `NOTIFY mymessage, 'blah-blah'` sql script and then close the connection, if there is no current listener listening to the channel "mymessage", the channel will be removed, which means that the payload 'blah-blah' will be lost.

Does anyone knows how to configure the postgresql database to make a created notification channel permanent so as to prevent message lost? Or, does anyone knows how to prevent a detected event in a postgresql table from being lost?

Thanks

Comment: "how to prevent a detected event in a postgresql table from being lost" - what do you mean?..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-listen.html) state:

> all the sessions **currently listening** on that notification channel are
>   notified

(emphasis mine). So no - there is nothing to configure.

If you want to save some message somewhere so other sessions could later read it, you should use publicly readable table for it Eg: `(message_id bigint, message_text text)`. Of course it will require more one more relation like `(last_listened_message_id bigint, pid int)` not to read ALL messages once and once again.

And if you want to mock up channels, you should either create more similar tables or add columns to two above...